# Powerbook with mic and headphones: I don't hear my voice. What is the solution?

Tags: headphones, microphone, powerbook

I have a Powerbook, OS 10.15.4, with a mic and use noise-cancelling headphones. When I speak during video conferencing, I do not hear myself (other than the noise conducted by the bone of my hard head). What solution is there to allow me to hear the conversation of the video conferencing, as well as the input from my mic? I am not geeky enough to figure with one out. Thx

Comment: Powerbook, running Catalina? Could you edit to provide *accurate* information, including Mac, headset & application information.

Comment: You *shouldn't* hear your voice.  No headset feeds back your voice through the earphone.

Comment: You could probably do this with [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/), but it's expensive if this is all you want it for. Or with [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower), which is free, but harder to set up. As others have said, however, not hearing your own voice is generally preferable, as there's usually a slight delay which can be very distracting.

Comment: I usually listen with one of the headphone cups not placed over my ear. Its the only way it works.